# Dense subset in sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to prove that $F=\{x=\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in l^2(\mathbb{N}):\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n=0\}$ is dense in the sequence space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

I think it should be an easy exercise, but I don't see why an arbitrary sequence $x \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ is the limit of one in F.

Any hint would be of help, thanks!

Comment: For a standard unit vector $e_m$, take the sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n=e_m-\sum_{i=1}^n e_i/n$. Then $x_n\rightarrow x$. This implies the result. If you wish though, you can do something similar for an arbitrary $x$ (the point is the vector $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i/n$ has $\ell_1$-norm $1$ and small $\ell_2$-norm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $F$ is not dense, then its closure is not the whole space. Therefore, there is a non-zero functional that vanishes on $F$. In a Hilbert space all (continuous) functionals are of the form $(\cdot, y)$ for some $y$.

Assume $y\in\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is such that $(x,y)=0$ for all $x\in F$.

Then $y$ is orthogonal to all vectors of the form $e_i-e_j\in F$ where $e_i$ has a $1$ in the $i$-th component and zeros otherwise. Since $0=(e_i-e_j,y)=\overline{y_i}-\overline{y_j}$, it follows that all components of $y$ are equal. This is only possible if $y=0$.